# How do you set the maximum recursion depth in?

Tags: r, recursion

I am running some R code that has a recursion depth of 5000 and I get the following error:

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
>   Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

How do I set the recursion depth in R?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah. Found it by reading the error message. This will set the recursion depth to 100000

```
> options(expressions= 100000)
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this.  You can set it, and using "options()" again, shows it set:

> options(expressions=255)
>   options()
>   ....
>   $expressions
>   [1] 255
>   ....

But unfortunately, it doesn't work.   The recursion fails in exactly the same way.  I've tried stripping the many extra columns off my data, and it doesn't help.

I originally solved this problem with a for() loop, but it's about 70k rows of data, and as any experienced R programmer knows, you're doomed to very long runs once you put a for() loop in with a big data set.

This is R version 3.4.1, running on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: why are you setting it to only  255?  The default value is 5000, it can be set as large as 500000.  When I run `options(expressions=10000); options("expressions")==10000` R returns TRUE ... I don't think turning a slow `for` loop into a recursion is actually going to help at all!