# Recursive function with variable number of arguments

Tags: r, recursion

I am trying to build a function to calculate the following formula

```
f(x) = X1*B1 + X2*B2 ... + Xn * Bn
```

In order to do this I find it useful ... and recursiveness.

This is my approach to the problem:

```
resolve_polinom <- function(x, b, ...){

  n <- length(list(...))
  func_args <- list(...)

  if (n == 0){ 
    # If there are no more elements on ... 
    return(x * b)

  }else{
    # If ... contains elements then 
    return(x * b + resolve_polinom(x= ..1, b= ..2, list(...)[-c(1,2)]))
  }
}

# list(...)[-c(1,2)]
```

This is my attempt to substract the first two elements that I want to pass as the first two arguments.

How would you do this?

Another problem I will be facing is that I would like to do this with columns from a data.table .

#### Examples:

```
resolve_polinom(2,3) = 6
expected result = 6 
calculation to get the result = 2*3 = 6


resolve_polinom(2,3,5,7)
expected result = 41 
Calculations to get the result = 2*3 + 5*7 = 6 + 35 = 41

resolve_polinom(3,5,1,2)
expected result = 17 
Calculations to get the result = 3*5 + 1*2 = 15 + 2 = 17
```

Comment: please share a sample of your data. It seems they might be a less complicated way of doing the same thing, starting from your data.table. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a bad idea to create recursive functions in R (if you can't guarantee that you won't exceed the [maximum evaluation nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26448869/1412059)).

If you insist on your way of calling the function, I'd suggest this:

```
resolve_polinom <- function(...) {
  values <- c(...)
  m <- matrix(values, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  sum(m[,1] * m[, 2])
}
```

Of course, the proper way in R (and much better software design) would be a function that expects two vectors `x` and `b` as input:

```
resolve_polinom <- function(x, b) {
  sum(x * b)
}
```

The latter should work easily if you have two corresponding columns in the data.table.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is matrix multiplication. where x is a matrix with a certain amount of rows/observations and n columns, and b is a vector of length n, with the coefficients.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(314)

x <- matrix(c(rep(1,10),sample(1:10,30, replace = T)), ncol = 4)

b <- 1:4

# multiply the elements of the first observation in x with the elements of b, and then take the sum.
sum(x[1,] * b)

# with matrix multiplication you can do this for all observations at once:
x %*% b
```

Comment: Ah, I think you nailed what they actually want to do.