# What is the max recursion depth of user function in R?

Tags: r, recursion

I am curious what is the depth of recursion when running a user-defined recursive function. Let's take the following simple function as an example

```
f <- function(n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
        return(n)
    }
    mean(c(f(n - 1), f(n - 2)))
}
```

As seen above, the function is written in a recursive manner.

When I ran `f(2000)`, I was given

```
> f(2000)
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Is there any limitation of recursion numbers in R? If there is, where can I find it or how should I know the limitation?

Comment: Relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448869/how-do-you-set-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in - The error message could probably be a bit more explicit that `options("expressions")` contains the current setting.

Comment: I think the dup answers all. The default value is `options("expressions")` (which seems to be 5000 by default) and that can be altered.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for the link. Now I see it.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. I have one more question. If the default is 5000, why the error pops up when we have `n = 2000`?

Comment: Things like mean() and c() are also being placed on the call stack also. You aren’t calling your function directly.